# Checking checkboxes in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several rows of checkboxes. The scenario is that when I click a checkbox in the first row, and when I click another checkbox in the second or third row and within the same column, the previous checked checkbox is unchecked and the new one is checked. This is working fine. My issue is that when I uncheck the newly checked checkbox, it should re-check the previous checkbox checked. Anyone who can help me with this please ?

The demo is as per below.

```js
$('.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();      //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked");             //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this;                               //Checkbox object

  $('.js-cars-item').each(function() {         //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
  });
  
   var checkeds = [];
  $(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-3">
      <label for="car-4-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-3">
      <label for="car-5-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-4">
      <label for="car-1-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-4">
      <label for="car-2-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-4">
      <label for="car-3-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-4">
      <label for="car-4-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-4">
      <label for="car-5-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-5">
      <label for="car-1-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-5">
      <label for="car-2-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-5">
      <label for="car-3-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-5">
      <label for="car-4-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-5">
      <label for="car-5-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6>
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6">
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6">
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-6">
      <label for="car-4-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-6">
      <label for="car-5-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-7>
      <label for="car-1-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-7">
      <label for="car-2-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-7">
      <label for="car-3-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-7">
      <label for="car-4-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-7">
      <label for="car-5-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-8">
      <label for="car-1-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-8">
      <label for="car-2-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-8">
      <label for="car-3-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-8">
      <label for="car-4-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-8">
      <label for="car-5-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what happed when we uncheck another checkbox instead of newly checked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your javascript code, please try this:

```js
$('.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();      //Get the index - Number  in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked");             //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this;                               //Checkbox object
  if(chk)
  { //If it is checked 
    $('.previous_'+idx).removeClass('previous_'+idx); //Remove the 'previous_$index' class from the checkbox
    $('.js-cars-item').find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]:checked').not(obj).addClass('previous_'+idx).prop("checked", false); //set the 'previous_$index' class to an existing checked checkbox and remove the checked property
  }
  else if($('.previous_'+idx).length)
  { //If the 'previous_$index' class is available while uncheck the current checkbox
    $('.previous_'+idx).prop("checked", true).removeClass('previous_'+idx); //set the 'previous_$index' class's checkbox to checked and remove this class
    $(obj).addClass('previous_'+idx); //set the 'previous_$index' class to the currently unchecked checkbox
  }
   var checkeds = [];
  $(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-3">
      <label for="car-4-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-3">
      <label for="car-5-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-4">
      <label for="car-1-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-4">
      <label for="car-2-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-4">
      <label for="car-3-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-4">
      <label for="car-4-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-4">
      <label for="car-5-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-5">
      <label for="car-1-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-5">
      <label for="car-2-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-5">
      <label for="car-3-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-5">
      <label for="car-4-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-5">
      <label for="car-5-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>        </
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6">
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6">
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6">
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-6">
      <label for="car-4-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-6">
      <label for="car-5-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-7">
      <label for="car-1-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-7">
      <label for="car-2-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-7">
      <label for="car-3-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-7">
      <label for="car-4-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-7">
      <label for="car-5-7"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-8">
      <label for="car-1-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-8">
      <label for="car-2-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-8">
      <label for="car-3-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-8">
      <label for="car-4-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-8">
      <label for="car-5-8"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.. I am having an issue with this one. Could you please check ?

Comment: By default, all the checkboxes in the first row will be checked and disabled to prevent unchecking in the first row.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, please try this https://jsfiddle.net/Saravanakumar/jtwa9vtz/

Comment: You can find this https://jsfiddle.net/Saravanakumar/jtwa9vtz/3/ fiddle with updated comments.
1. I have added 'first_row' class in first row div
2. By default all the checkbox in a first row has been selected and disabled
3. some JS update made based on the first_row class

Comment: @saravanakumar : Could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596430/validate-checkboxes-when-checking-the-same-order-within-the-same-column-in-jquer/50596556#50596556 ?